# How to include/add/link 2nd script tag into 1st script tag?

Tags: javascript, tags

Is there possible to add/link 2nd script tag into 1st script tag? I am not sure but is there any way to do like this?

```
 <script src="script/1.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
       <?php if($show1) { if($show1 == '1') { ?> 
             //--------
          <?php }else{?>
              <script src="script/2.js"></script> 
       <?php }}?>
});

    </script>
```

Comment: why do you want to add another script of a certain script?

Comment: No. Why would you need that? The scripts have to be declared one after another.

Comment: I update my question look....

Comment: the script should be declared after the first script not inside the script

Comment: Not working because when i add 2nd script after 1st script then the 2nd script not working..

Comment: the answer for this is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by doing it like this by using `file_get_contents` in php and use echo

```
    <script src="script/1.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
       <?php if($show1) { if($show1 == '1') { ?> 
             //--------
          <?php }else{?>
                <!--<script src="script/2.js"></script> -->
                <?php 
                    $js2content = file_get_contents('script/2.js');
                    echo $js2content;
                 ?>
       <?php }}?>
});

    </script>'
```

Comment: i think echo should be `$js2content` ? @jameshwart lopez

Comment: Thanks bro but is there any way to encode or hide original code of script 2.js ? but orginal code must be run at the same time in the script tag

Comment: you want hide script2.js? you really are an exceptional type of person .

Comment: Ha ha.Not hide but trying to encode it. is it possible?

Comment: no you can't because if you do that the browser cannot recognize your js script anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a module loader library. There are several, depending on whether you want synchronous or asynchronous module loading.

For the most basic usage, have a look at **[Browserify](http://browserify.org/)**.

Usage example:

```
<script>
    var module1 = require('./script/1');
    var module2 = require('./script/2');

    // Rest of your code here...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
script tag should be coded after another tag **not inside a script tag**

```
 <script src="script/1.js"></script>
       <?php if($show1) { if($show1 == '1') { ?> 
             //--------
          <?php }else{?>
              <script src="script/2.js"></script> 
       <?php }}?>
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: Not working because when i add 2nd script after 1st script then the 2nd script not working..

Comment: im thinking why do you want that script inside script

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest `script` tags. The way `script` tags work, the browser reads the opening tag and then starts building up a string of the code therein without interpreting that code at all. It stops doing that the first time it sees the exact sequence `< / s c r i p t >`. The browser will always stop at the first of those it finds, and crucially it ***ignores*** any intervening opening tag sequence, like `< s c r i p t >`. This is because the browser doesn't parse the script code, that's not its job. It's a separation of concerns thing. (`script` tags probably shouldn't be tags at all, but rather something more like a `CDATA` structure. But they're what we have.)

Comment: what does `$show1` contain? how it is changing inside `script`? cant you put this in main page?

Comment: yes $show1 from admin side and can change inside script @Mike